# Create a div inside a container with the same width and height with percentages

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has a height of 30% of its parent and 100% of its width so it changes when the user resizes the window and it doesnt have equal width and height.

Im trying to make a circle centered and equal in width and height.

So I have set the height of the circle to 80% and now I just need to set the width to the same as its height. Here is the code:

```
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image">

    </div>
  </div>

.image-container{
  height:30%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80%;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2tsa3gwj/1/

Comment: setting it to 80% will do 80% of the width, making it really wide and short

Comment: I dont get what you mean, How do i set it 80% of 30% if I dont know what the height (30%) is

Comment: Sorry, I see what you are asking now. I don't think you can do it with CSS, you may be able to do it with SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all examples out there about using CSS to fix aspect ratio is dependent on the width: in your case, you actually rely on a percentage height to determine width, which can be a bit of a problem.

One way to get around the problem is to simply inject a "sizer" element with a 1:1 aspect ratio, and use it to determine the size of the `.image` element by allowing it to expand to 100% of the height of its parent. This can be done with using a dummy `<svg>` element with a square viewbox, e.g. `0 0 1 1`:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg>
```

The only catch is that if you have any content inside the `.image` element, it has to be positioned absolutely so that it does not interfere with the sizing mandated by the `<svg>` element.

```css
.body{
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner{
  background-color: white;
  width: 75%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.image-container{
  height:30%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sizer {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image">
          <svg class="sizer" viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou this is very helpful

Comment: This did not give me the same width/height when in full screen